# .htaccess having issue with RedirectMatch

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a site where I need to redirect from one url to another.

The current url: `www.somesite.com/people/johndoe/?id=10`

The desired url: `www.somesite.com/people/?id=10`

I am trying this in my .htaccess file but to no avail:

`RedirectMatch ^/people/(.*)$ /people/?id=$1`

This returns:

```
www.somesite.com/people/?id=johndoe
```

I have looked up many similar questions on this site and elsewhere, but cannot find a solution that works. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not correct.

Use this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(people)/.+$ /$1
```

Comment: This worked but apparently I misunderstood the requirements for my task. Can you chat for one minute so I can try to resolve this outside of comments or a new question?

Comment: Apparantly I need to have the original url still appear for SEO reasons, but the actual page which should be called is the modified url you worked out.