# RewriteRule in .htaccess is not working

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a site where I need to show one URL for SEO reasons, but the actual landing page is a slightly different URL. I originally thought the requirement was [to show the url which actually exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807856/htaccess-having-issue-with-redirectmatch), but I was incorrect.

The required url: www.somesite.com/people/johndoe/?id=10

The url which actually exists: www.somesite.com/people/?id=10

I am trying this in my .htaccess file but to no avail:

```
RewriteRule ^/person/.+$ /person/$1 [R=301.L]
```

This doesn't appear to change anything and I am told my url doesn't exist. 
I have looked up many similar questions on this site and elsewhere, but cannot find a solution that works. Thanks in advance

Edit (existing .htaccess):

```
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
#AuthName "username"
#AuthName "username"
#AuthUserFile "/home/something/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
#require valid-user

AuthName "username"
AuthUserFile "/home/something/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.sitename\.org\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not sure why you're matching `pperson` here.

Answer (score 0):

For doing internal rewrites use `mod_rewrite` rules with using `R` flag:

Use this code in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(people)/.+$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: There is already an existing rewrite rule ending in [R=301,L]. Can this come after?

Comment: Hmm can you paste your current .htaccess in question. Ideally this should be after 301 rules.

Comment: I have added this as an edit in my question. Thanks,

Comment: Is `/people/johndoe/?id=10` a WP URL (I mean WP post or page)?

Comment: The 'id' sends to a wordpress page, but the 'johndoe' is not part of that page. The actual wordpress page is '/people/?id=10'

Comment: Hmm with WP in place I think internal rewrites won't be easily possible. Try inserting my suggested rule just below `RewriteBase` line. However I suspect it might not work due to WP URI handling.

Comment: it gets me to the page, but the not-optimized url still appears: person/?id=10 . I want person/johndoe/$id=10

Comment: You mean you are entering URI as `www.sitename.org/person/johndoe/$id=10` and it is being redirected to  `www.sitename.org/person/$id=10` in the browser? Make sure you test in a new browser and your URL with `www`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and tested on the wrong location. I'm still being told that /person/johndoe/?id=10 does not exist

Comment: ok that is what I suspected WP will do. If you make it `RewriteRule ^(people)/.+$ /$1 [L,NC,R]` it will work but URL will change.

Comment: So that gets me to the page, but without the desired url. Any more ides? Thanks so much for your time and help

Comment: No unfortunately only way to handle it via WP rewrite hooks (but I am not WP expert)

Answer (score 0):

Your rewriterule *condition* cannot include a leading /. It is stripped off. Use

```
RewriteRule ^person/.+$ /person/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also note that you had a period in the flags, not a comma.

Lose the " and \'s in the last rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sitename.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I don't know if you're going to get in any trouble with multiple 301s in action. It may depend upon the server configuration. Do you need for the revised URI to go back to the visitor and be seen in their browser? If not, lose the 301 on that rewrite rule.

Document what you're doing and why, with comments. For example, your last two lines are to force www.sitename.org instead of sitename.org.